# Double Click Selection IntelliJ Idea

Tags: front-end, windows

How do I support double click selection in IntelliJ Idea?

I'm referring to halirutan's plugin.

Comment: This might be closed which is fine by me because it is already answered.

Comment: That was... fast (the question and the comment). you can delete it yourself if you feel you no longer need an answer

Comment: @TheToad It is here for others/my convenience(and searching).  Lock it, Community Wiki, close it I don't really care.  It fixes one of my gripes with halirutan's plugin.  I might at a picture later.

Comment: Cool. FYI, you have an option to self answer when asking the question itself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following autohotkey script works.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class SunAwtFrame
~LButton::
if (A_PriorHotkey <> "~LButton" or A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 400)
{
    KeyWait, LButton
    return
}else{
    Send {Ctrl Down}{w}{Ctrl Up}
}
#IfWinActive
```